# converting div and its associated elements to canvas jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

Is there any way to convert HTML Div and its associated elements to canvas and the canvas to image Using Jquery? I already had a look on following website, It would only convert whole HTML page and render to body.Can anyone help me find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render HTML into canvas by going by SVG and its `foreignObject`. This is limited in the way you can't render images or external sources in any way (you would need to extract those and render them separately later).

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TGKBL/)**

**Result:**

[image: demo]

Lets define some HTML we want to render:

```
<div id="html">
    <div style="border:2px dotted #f73;font:12px sans-serif">
        <em>This</em> is
        <span style="color:#00f;border:1px solid #777;padding:0 4px">HTML</span>
        drawn into <strong>canvas</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we can build an inline SVG and add this html using the `html` id of the first div tag:

```
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
           "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
           "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" + 

           /// extract the html content of div
           document.getElementById('html').innerHTML +

           "</div>" +
           "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
```

Next step is to build a `Blob` object so we can reference the SVG as url to use with canvas where we draw it as an image:

```
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"} );

/// create an url that we can use for the image tag
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function () {

    /// now we can draw the "html" to canvas.
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
```

You can wrap this into a function that takes an id and canvas as argument and deals with external content and images.

Comment: Thanks @Cryptoburner. But, it doesn't work in IE. Is there any other way to do it in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the browser won't render HTML into a canvas.

It would be a potential security risk if you could, as HTML can include content (in particular images and iframes) from third-party sites. If `canvas` could turn HTML content into an image and then you read the image data, you could potentially extract privileged content from other sites.

To get a canvas from HTML, you'd have to basically write your own HTML renderer from scratch using `drawImage` and `fillText`, which is a potentially huge task. There's [one such attempt here](http://www.cuppadev.co.uk/a-browser-within-a-browser-htmlcanvas/) but it's a bit dodgy and a long way from complete. (It even attempts to parse the HTML/CSS from scratch, which I think is crazy! It'd be easier to start from a real DOM node with styles applied, and read the styling using `getComputedStyle` and relative positions of parts of it using `offsetTop` et al.)

Comment: refer the link http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/, it renders whole html to canvas. why can't we convert the particular div to canvas

Comment: ur question is converting div html element to canvas i have replied based on it and i am not sure about the link u have provided and its supportive nature..

Comment: you making no sense. if i have access to DOM tree, i could read any privilege data. You made up that reason.